# How to run a tail -f log monitor script as a systemd service

Tags: bash, 15.10, systemd, awk

I have a shell script which monitors the auth log to alert on new system logins, and it works fine when I start it manually, but when I try to load it as a service using systemd service is fails to load.  I've tried a myriad of variations in the script, but I'm not sure how to localize the issue...

journalctl -xe gives me the following useless error message...

```
-- Subject: Unit quackme.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit quackme.service has begun starting up.
Dec 09 11:27:34 dc1 systemd[1]: quackme.service: Control process exited,     code=exited status=5
Dec 09 11:27:34 dc1 systemd[1]: Failed to start quackme.
-- Subject: Unit quackme.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit quackme.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

The service is defined as such...

```
[Unit]
Description=quackme

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/myuser/quack/quackmeservicescript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm not sure if it matters what the shell script says, but here it is...

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/tail -fn0 /var/log/auth.log | awk '/New session/ { system("wget http://example.com/fut/9bgfej8s755sktgh0o3irgag0/alert.jsp") }'
```

Comment: I think this is answered by turning off tail's buffer and/or using a while loop as described in this superuser question. [superuser q 742238](http://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk)

Comment: this one shows how to use an awk script that acts like tail -f. [stackoverflow q 9101296](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101296/implement-tail-with-awk) Googling for "awk tail" had these and a few other interesting hits.

Comment: It's not the buffering  - I think the issue is that it doesn't launch in a new process.  I don't see how the awk version of tail would be any different.

Comment: Not sure how much this could help a 6-year old question, but using an upper-case F on the tail would essentially also add a "--retry" to the mix essentially, allowing the tail to keep trying to display the resulting lines until the `/var/log/auth.log` becomes available.